# My OS does not respond to Ctrl+ Alt+ F1

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

I'm using a Lenovo system with Lubuntu and I'm trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> properly.  It does not respond.  Any ideas on to getting it to work?

Comment: You can change the `Fn` behavior in the Bios. I you enable it, you won't need to press `Fn` for typing `F1`, `F2` ... but need `Fn` to increase/decrease volume for example; it's just an option in the Bios

Answer (score 0):

So Manoj Sawai put up a great comment that on laptops when entering Ctrl Alt F1 it is necessary to also hold down Fn.  That actually worked. Thanks.